# Reset Password via Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am building a workflow to reset the user's password on AD via GRAPH API using the power automate.

[image]

The above action is for generating the Access Token from my azure portal - Application (used for calling the graph api)

I have already given the required permissions for a password reset

[image]

I am also getting the correct access token. Now for the Password Reset HTTP

[image]

I have already logged in via a global admin user account but I'm still getting the below error

I have followed everything as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

But don't know why still getting the access denied error.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced this issue with few modification at my environment and it worked as expected***

Initially I only have added below permission as per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

[image]

**`My workflow`**

[image]

If you will use `grant_type=client_credentials`, then you will get general bearer token for resource `https://graph.microsoft.com` like below

[image]

[image]

Ultimately, you will get error too

[image]

I am using `https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token` URL and following request body.

```
client_id=<your client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=password&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&username=<username>&password=<password>
```

Here I have taken `grant_type: password` in order get the specified bearer token for `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` access only.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]